# Django select_for_update() for arbitrary object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make an atomic update an object whose type may vary. The structure looks something like this:

```py
class MyMixin(models.Model):
    size = models.BigIntegerField(null=False, default=0)

class SubClassA(MyMixin, models.Model):
    <...>

class SubClassB(MyMixin, models.Model):
    <...>

# obj is of type SubClassA or SubClassB
def some_func(obj):
    with db.transaction.atomic():
        # obj = SubClassA.objects.select_for_update().get(id=obj.id)  # How do I do this?
        obj.size = calculate()
        obj.save()
```

All of the examples I can find explicitly use the `<Class>.objects.select_for_update()` pattern but my problem is I don't know what the class will be at runtime. In my code, I *already have* an instance of the object/model but I need to re-fetch it from the database in order to lock it.

I'm trying to draw ideas from the "Pessimistic approach" found in this guide - https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2

Should I put a very simple method in `MyMixin` which allows me to set and save the `size`? Or I could explicitly check the `type` of the `obj` at runtime and have a bunch of `elif`s (to do something like `if/elif type(obj) == SubClassA: SubClassA.objects.select_for_update()...`)but that's both ugly and not very maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

You can always get the class of an object from its `__class__` attribute. So:

```
obj = obj.__class__.objects.select_for_update().get(id=obj.id)
```